# Can you specify attributes to be assigned to a specific class when there are global attributes?

Tags: css

In my CSS there is a global attribute that states all links are assigned a specific color

```
a {
   color: #f0842b
}
```

However there is a class I want to modify the color of the text for but the color setting in the style above is overriding the color I am trying to set for the class and even using !important is not overriding the color. Is there anyway I can do this? The code for the class is..

.hikashop_checkout_terms label {
    color:red !important;  <----What I am trying to over right it with.
    background-color:yellow !important
}

but no matter what i do, the output of the text for the class above always comes out the color of the text set for "a" . Please help. Thanks

Comment: can you share that part of your code? Is it <a class="hikashop_checkout_terms"></a> <label>...</label>

Comment: Sorry, I have a hard time understanding how to put code into this website. I will try my best i hope it comes out. I tried above but failed :(

Here is the CSS
First is the Global:
a {
  color: #f0842b
}

What I am trying to set it to
.hikashop_checkout_terms label {
 color:red !important;
}

I just provided the CSS code, do you need the php or html parts as well?

From the HTML the class is expands to a URL. So yes I think you are correct. But I am only trying to modify the CSS

<div id="hikashop_checkout_terms_1_7" class="hikashop_checkout_terms hikashop_checkout_terms_7">

Comment: can you include more of the html code? i dont see any label or a tags.

Comment: I don't know if I made any sense in how I am explaining this. I am not a code monkey but I am able to manuver through just able any code and do quite well on my own, just this has me stumped. If I knew how to use this site better I could probably provide your answers much easier. Since I am modifying the custom css file only I did not add any of the code that  shows the coding for the actual php / html / or anything. Please let me know if you need anything else and I will do my best to provide it. The div i pasted is from the html part that uses the css to render the link that Im referring too

Comment: Okay. So if you press ctrl U then you can search for <div id="hikashop_checkout_terms_1_7" class="hikashop_checkout_terms hikashop_checkout_terms_7"> and send more of the code you see under it (just need to see where the label is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:
      #shop_terms_and_cond{color:red;}

Comment: that's if the html is like this:<a class="hikashop_checkout_terms"> <label>hello</label></a> see if you can send the html part because the above worked for me so if it does not work for you then you must have it set up differently.

Comment: Here is the HTML...
 <label for="hikashop_checkout_terms_checkbox_1_7"><a href="#"  id="shop_terms_and_cond" onclick="window.hikashop.openBox(this,null,true); return false;">Please accept the Terms and Conditions before proceeding</a><div id="modal-shop_terms_and_cond" style="width:470px;margin-left:-235px" tabindex="-1" class="modal hide fade">
 <div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close novalidate" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3>Terms and Conditions</h3>
 </div>
<div class="modal-body">
 </div>
</div>

Comment: Basically the first "a { color: #f0842b }" is overridding anything I put in " .hikashop_checkout_terms label{color:red;}" <---there

Comment: Also if you could provide me a link that explains how to properly put code into a question / comment on here, I would be appreicative because I can never get anything to work. It always tells me it's formatted wrong. 

PS - if you go here  https://www.eutopiantrader.com/  put anything into your cart and click check out, at the bottom you will see the terms and conditions statement (checkbox) that you must agree to before you can fully check out. That is where I am having an issue. I can give you the login / pss for a test account so you don't have to register if that will help.

Comment: This is what you need to do: #shop_terms_and_cond{color:red;}

Comment: Let me try that. Stand by.

Comment: OMG!! You soooo Rock! Ok, Can you please help me understand why that worked? And while I think I do understand why let me explain my confusion. If I use this .hikashop_checkout_terms label { background-color:yellow;} I get the background color over the exact same url, so why is it that the text color would not change with just using color:red in my original code but what you gave me works?   Thank you SOOO Much!

Comment: Now can you please help me get the background coloring to only span the text and not the enter width of the window? :)  I tried display:inline as I saw in another post but that doens't work, and that post people we giving suggestions like create a table etc, which is way too over kill imo..  If you ever want to purchase anything from my store you earned yourself a coupon for helping me! :D

Comment: This is because you only specified to change the div but you didn't target the a inside that div with your css. Since the a already had a style it was overridden.

Comment: You already have .hikashop_checkout_terms{background-color:yellow!important} remove that.

Comment: You have thus far been the absolutely most amazingly helpful person I have ever had the pleasure of working with on this site. Thank you so very much Esther! I really appreciate it! I wish there was a way to give you a thumbs up or something! :)  Thanks again!! You have made my day!

Comment: My pleasure :) You can choose my answer as helpful.

Comment: Now I have to learn how to write questions where I can add code correctly to it without it yelling at me that I did it wrong or accepting it looking horrible like my question did.. That is going to be a challenge. I started a new account here because I had created so many horrible questions in the past, I looked like a fool lol

Comment: If you are posting a question or answer you can click on the button that says code (when hovered) and paste it there.

Comment: I have tried that and it deletes my code and says that my indents are wrong. I tried doing that for what we were just discussing and it still put it in all wonky. I will give it another go with my next questions :)  I also just learned how to use the Web Maker Chrome Extension to test your suggested changes and it worked great!

Comment: Hmm. I don't think I can help with the code issue but I'm happy the rest is working for you. Good luck!

Comment: That's OK. It's something I have to keep working on... :) PS- Check your Email. I sent you a quick run down of the site, and Im going to send you coupon code :)  Thank you so much again!! I look forward to chatting again soon! Cheers!